# Regular Expressions help (overlap)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

After doing some research here on stack overflow i found that one can use re.finditer() to get overlapping matches, but for my specific case it doesn't seem to work.  I want my regex to extract a date surrounded by non-alphanumeric (\W) chars in the form YYYY-MM-DD.  This work fine if two matches have at least two \W chars between them.  My question is: how do I augment my expression so that it will extract dates from a string such as this one:
" 2016-02-29 4354-09-21 1900-03-15 1576-05-16"  This only extracts 2016-02-29 and 1900-03-15 even though the others are valid.
Here is the code:

```
# Find Dates
# dmoj
# author: Aniekan Umoren
# date: 2016-02-15

import re
#input: int N (number of line)
#input: lines containing dates (YYYY-MM-DD) in them
#output: a list of all VALID dates

# turns it into a reegex object which can now use methods like findall
exp1 = re.compile("\W([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\W")
exp2 = re.compile("([0-9]+)-*") 
thirty = (4,6,9,11)
N = int(input())
found = []
for i in range(N):
    line = input()
    matches = exp1.finditer(line)
    # returns a tuple of the matched capturing groups
    #(or the entire match if there are no capturing groups)
    found.extend([str(x.group(1)) for x in matches])

for it in found:
    date = [int(x) for x in exp2.findall(it)]
    isthirty = False
    if (date[1] > 12 or date[2] > 31):
        continue
    if (date[1] in thirty): isthirty = True
    if (isthirty and date[2] <= 30):
        print(it)
    elif (date[1] == 2):
        if (date[0] % 4 == 0 and date[2] <= 29):
            print(it)
        elif (date[0] % 4 != 0 and date[2] <= 28):
            print(it)
    elif (not isthirty and date[2] <= 31):
        print(it)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`finditer` will never give you overlapping matches. From the docs (emphasis mine):

> Return an iterator yielding `MatchObject` instances over all **non-overlapping** matches for the RE *pattern* in *string*

`\W` will consume the space, making it unavailable for another match. Use lookaheads and lookbehinds to avoid having them in the match:

```
exp1 = re.compile("(?<!\w)([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})(?!\w)")
```

`(?<!\w)` means "There is not `\w` just before this"; `(?!\w)` is "There is not `\w` just after this". This also frees you from having to put a space at the start and at the end of the string.

Comment: THANKYOU SOO MUCH.  You don't know how long i've been going at this problem

Comment: Since you use the `\w` class, you can replace the lookarounds with word boundaries.